# Order of an element in $F_2[X]/X^5+X^2+1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $Q=X^5+X^2+1 \in F_2[X]$. Q is irreducible.

Let $K=F_2[X]/Q$.

Let $\alpha$ be the class of $X$ in $K$.

I am trying to find the inverse of $\alpha$ in $K$.

What I did:

I am new to finite fields theory so I tried to understand $\alpha$.

$\alpha \in \overline{X}$ means $X-\alpha \in I_\alpha=\{P\in K[X]: P(\alpha)=0\}$. Is that accurate?

I know also from my course that $(1, \alpha, . . . , \alpha^4 )$ is a basis of K so $|K|= 2^5$.

I don't know how to follow-up. any help much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: $x^5+x^2=-1=1\implies x(x^4+x)=1$ so $x^{-1}= x^4+x$.

Comment: Such that you know for the future, if you have Euclidean division and want to compute the inverse of $A$, which is relatively prime to the modulus $B$, then iterate the division to find $M,N$ such that $AM+BN=1$ (Bezout's lemma). Then $\mod{B}$, $AM=1$. Therefore, $M$ is the inverse of $A$. In your case it only takes one long division to get $x(x^4+x)-(x^5+x^2+1)=1$.

Comment: Thank you @lulu. I still don't understand why is $Q(\alpha)=0$?

Comment: That's what $K$ means.  You are building a field extension.  To do it, you start with your base field, $\mathbb F_2$ and you add a root, $\alpha$, of $x^5+x^2+1$.  That means you are adjoining an element $\alpha$ which satisfies $\alpha^5+\alpha^2+1=0$.

Comment: @lulu Many thanks for your explanation!